# Python run .exe with input

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to use a script to call an executable program and input some instructions in the exe program (a DOS window) to run this exe program (output not required)

For example if I directly run the program I'll double click it and type as follows:

```
load XXX.txt
oper
quit
```

Here's my code, fwiw I do not have a deep understanding about subprocess.

```
import subprocess
import os
os.chdir('D:/Design/avl3.35/Avl/Runs')
Process=subprocess.Popen(['avl.exe'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
Process.communicate(b'load allegro.avl\n')
```

When I run this code, I get the following:

```
 ===================================================
  Athena Vortex Lattice  Program      Version  3.35
  Copyright (C) 2002   Mark Drela, Harold Youngren

  This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY,
    subject to the GNU General Public License.

  Caveat computor
 ===================================================

 ==========================================================
   Quit    Exit program

  .OPER    Compute operating-point run cases
  .MODE    Eigenvalue analysis of run cases
  .TIME    Time-domain calculations

   LOAD f  Read configuration input file
   MASS f  Read mass distribution file
   CASE f  Read run case file

   CINI    Clear and initialize run cases
   MSET i  Apply mass file data to stored run case(s)

  .PLOP    Plotting options
   NAME s  Specify new configuration name

 AVL   c>  
 Reading file: allegro.avl  ...

 Configuration: Allegro-lite 2M                                             

   Building surface: WING                                    
     Reading airfoil from file: ag35.dat
     Reading airfoil from file: ag36.dat
     Reading airfoil from file: ag37.dat
     Reading airfoil from file: ag38.dat
```

At line 145 of file ../src/userio.f (unit = 5, file = 'stdin') #!!!!Error here!!

Fortran runtime error: End of file                             #!!!!Error here!!

```
   Building duplicate image-surface: WING (YDUP)                             

   Building surface: Horizontal tail                         

   Building duplicate image-surface: Horizontal tail (YDUP)                  

   Building surface: Vertical tail                           

 Mach =    0.0000  (default)
 Nbody =   0      Nsurf =   5      Nstrp =  64      Nvor  = 410

 Initializing run cases...
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this, nor do I know why the error prompt shows inside the codes.  After searching I see that `communicate` method is to wait for the process to finish and return all the output, though I do not need output, but I still don't know what to do.

Could you explain what is happening here and how could I finish what I want to do?

Comment: Why are you using a Python script? if using CLI is working, why don't you use a batch script?

Comment: @XavierC. cause this is a small part of a Program and all codes in Python